# Adding a new column based on the column header

Tags: unix, r

I am working with R to convert several million lines of data in a single column like this.....

```
fixedStep chrom=chr7 start=10239 step=1
0.064
0.064
0.064
0.055
0.055
0.089
0.076
fixedStep chrom=chr7 start=10262 step=1
0.076
0.076
0.089
0.076
0.076
0.076
0.076
0.089
0.089
0.076
0.089
0.076
0.089
0.089
fixedStep chrom=chr7 start=10398 step=1
0.076
0.089
0.089
0.089
0.089
0.076
```

to this......

```
10239 0.064
10240 0.064
10241 0.064
10242 0.055
10243 0.055
10244 0.089
10245 0.076
10262 0.076
10263 0.076
10264 0.089
10265 0.076
10266 0.076
10267 0.076
10268 0.076
10269 0.089
10270 0.089
10271 0.076
10272 0.089
10273 0.076
10274 0.089
10275 0.089
10398 0.076
10399 0.089
10400 0.089
10401 0.089
10402 0.089
10403 0.076
```

i.e., I want to add a new column of numbers (either before or after the data, in the example above, it is before the data). The numbers of the new column start from `start=value`, and increments by 1 (`step=1`), until a new column header (`fixedStep chrom=chr7 start=10262 step=1`) is reached. When this happens the numbers start from `start=new value`, and again increments by 1 (`step=1`), until a new column header..and so on and so forth.

Since it is a large file, I cannot load the it into R workspace. It would be good to combine it with UNIX/linux tools to perform this operation.

Comment: The "increments by 1" property seems not to be true for your example output?

Comment: @Jouni : It is, but you have different headers in the file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you said unix...

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
/^fixedStep/ {
  i=int(substr($0,match($0,"start=")+6))
  d=int(substr($0,match($0,"step=")+5))
}
!/^f/ { print i, $0; i+=d }
```

What it does: on lines that start with "fixedStep" it finds the position of "start=", adds 6 (the length of "start="), takes the substring starting at that position and truncates it to an integer value and assigns it to `i` (in awk integers and strings are pretty interchangeable, and "12345 step=1" works fine as an integer with value 12345, but we want to print only the integer part later so it makes sense to truncate it here). Similarly for "step=".

On lines not starting with "f", it prints `i` and the line, and adds `d` to `i`.

Comment: thank you for your unix code. I enclosed it as a *.sh script and it runs beautifully. I tested the script on a file with 152 million lines and did seem to take a while to run. Since I am new to unix I am not able to parse your code. I understood the first part of awk where you are looking for lines that begin with 'fixedStep'. Can you give a beginner explanation  of how it works? Also is there a way to check if the out put is correct? Thanks again...

Comment: I added an explanation. If it's too slow, note that there are several [implementations of awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK#Versions_and_implementations) that may have speed differences. I would try at least [mawk](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/) which is claimed to be fast (though I have not made any measurements myself).

Comment: Also, it's not a shell script, it's an awk script! But it doesn't matter what you name the file.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the function `readLines` to scan the file one by one. This way you don't have to load everything into the memory. One possibility would be to use following function.

Not concise, not fast (as you read line by line), but it gives you the dataframe without reading in the whole file. If you only want to generate a new file, by all means use something else but R. The awk solution given here seems the best shot at it.

```
ReadFile <- function(file){

  DF <- data.frame(ID=numeric(0),value=numeric(0))

   while(1){

    z <- readLines(file,1)
    if(length(z)==0 | z=="") {break}

    Start <- if(grepl("start",z))
      as.numeric(gsub(".+start=(\\d+).+","\\1",z))

    if(is.null(Start)){
        DF <- rbind(DF,
            data.frame(ID=ID,value=as.numeric(z))
        )
        ID <- ID + 1
    } else {
      ID <- Start
    }
  }
  return(DF)
}
```

Tested on your data :

```
ZZ <- textConnection("fixedStep chrom=chr7 start=10239 step=1
0.064
0.076
fixedStep chrom=chr7 start=10262 step=1
0.076
0.089
fixedStep chrom=chr7 start=10398 step=1
0.045
0.089
")

> ReadFile(ZZ)
     ID value
1 10239 0.064
2 10240 0.076
3 10262 0.076
4 10263 0.089
5 10398 0.045
6 10399 0.089
```